# DOM to XML transformer logic

Tags: mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio

Can someone please explain to me why a `DOM to XML` transformer converts the output of a `Web Service Consumer` to an XML String representation? 
The output of the Web Service Consumer is a `org.mule.module.ws.consumer.NamespaceRestorerXMLStreamReader`.

According to the official docs:

> The DomToXml transformer converts DOM objects to XML, the XmlToDom
>   transformer converts XML strings to DOM objects, and the
>   DomToOutputHandler transformer converts from a DOM to an OutputHandler
>   serialization.

They refer to a W3C DOM object, which is to my knowledge the html DOM that is used in web browsers?

Thanks

Comment: It converts an XML payload (Document, XML stream, Source, etc.) to a serialized String representation not only W3C DOM. see https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/domtoxml-transformer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It refers to a [org.w3c.dom.Document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) which in Java can represent either HTML or XML.
In Mule an XML is just a string containing the XML. You can use the DOM interface to operate in the XML nodes using Java APIs or the string XML when needed.