# Unable to understand Mule 3 expressions

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mulesoft, mule4

I know Mule 4 but came across Mule 3 application and trying to understand some expressions and connectors. Can somebody explain.

Set Variable expression 1:

```
#[dw("p(flowVars.someKey)")]
```

Set Variable expression 2: (input XML payload)

```
#[xpath3('local-name(//*:Body/*[1])')]
```

What does DOM to XML do?

Comment: Do you have a question about the expressions or about the Dom to xml transformer?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume these are 3 questions:

1. What does this expression do?

   #[dw("p(flowVars.someKey)")]

This is a MEL expression (MEL is the expression language in Mule 3) which executes a dynamic DataWeave expression, to obtain a configuration property, where the name of the configuration property is dynamically obtained from the value of flow variable `someKey`.

2. What does this expression do?

   #[xpath3('local-name(//*:Body/*[1](https://docs.mulesoft.com/xml-module/0.3.9/xpath#the-xpath3-function))')]

This MEL expression call the [xpath3()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/xml-module/0.3.9/xpath#the-xpath3-function) function to evaluate an [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) 3.0 expression on the payload.

3. What does DOM to XML do?
   This question has been [answered previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52415896/721855).

Comment: what will be the Mule 4 equivalent expression for this?
#[xpath3('local-name(//:Body/1)')]

Comment: It may be something like `#[ payload..Body[0] ]`. It depends on the expected input and output, which I don't know.

Comment: what will be equivalent xmlModule:xpath expression that I can use in Mule4 for below xpath3 expression?
 #[xpath3('local-name(//:Body/1)')]

Comment: see my previous comment or ask in a new question.